# How to install NuGet in PowerShell on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have acquired Windows 10 recently after working for years on Linux and would like to have **PSReadLine** completion module installed for that I first need to get **NuGet** which comes with VS Studio 2017. I installed VS Studio 2017 then opened PowerShell as admin and tried to install the module via `Install-Module -Name PSReadLine` but get:

```
WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider
'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package
has the tags.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:7468 char:21
+ ...     $null = PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider -Name $script:N ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-Pac
   kageProvider], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackagePro
   vider
```

I tried to google but so far no "solution" helped to get it installed. Can somebody help me to set this up please?

Comment: psreadline is a module which comes with the default windows powershell installation, no need to install it from packagemanagement... you also don't need VisualStudio to use nuget. VisualStudio contains a GUI to manage packages but to only install packages you don't need that. nuget is commandline-tool in the first place and can be downloaded as such from nuget.org

Comment: You can install the Powershell NuGet provider like this: `Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable TLS 2

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

# Try again
Install-Module MSOnline
```